# Stop radio button change

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010, radiobuttonlist

I have radio button list that calls a function.

If the function returns true then I want to change the value.

However if the function returns false then I do not want to change the value and keep the original selection value.

Currently it changes the value even when the statement returns false.

Any advice?

**ASP Page**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    DataSourceID="SqlData" DataTextField="Type" 
    DataValueField="TypeID">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**VB file**

```vb
Private selectionvalue As Integer   

Protected Sub rblType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rblType.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim CheckListValidation As Boolean = CheckListBox()

    If CheckListValidation = True Then
            selectionvalue = rblType.SelectedItem.Value
        Else
            rblType.SelectedItem.Value = selectionvalue
    End If

End Sub

Function CheckListBox() As Boolean

    If lstbox.Items.Count <> "0" Then
        If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to change option?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, " Change  Type") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Else
        Return True
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint?  Not sure what CheckListBox() is doing, but could this event be called more than once and your check is returning true on a subsequent call?  Is CheckListBox() changing the value, perhaps and not the code you've pasted?

Comment: Good point - Updated code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when `rblType_SelectedIndexChanged` is executed, the selected item is already changed and the `RadioButtonList` doesn't "remember" the previously selected value. You need to keep the previously selected value between postbacks in order to achieve this.

I would suggest using ViewState. Create a property in code behind to represent the ViewState value:

```vb
Private Property PreviousSelectedValue() As String
    Get
        If (ViewState("PreviousSelectedValue") Is Nothing) Then
            Return String.Empty
        Else
            Return ViewState("PreviousSelectedValue").ToString()
        End If
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        ViewState("PreviousSelectedValue") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

and in `rblType_SelectedIndexChanged`:

```vb
Protected Sub rblType_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rblType.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim CheckListValidation As Boolean = CheckListBox()

    If CheckListValidation = True Then
        'save the currently selected value to ViewState
        Me.PreviousSelectedValue = rblType.SelectedValue
    Else
        'get the previously selected value from ViewState 
        'and change the selected radio button back to the previously selected value
        If (Me.PreviousSelectedValue = String.Empty) Then
            rblType.ClearSelection()
        Else
            rblType.SelectedValue = Me.PreviousSelectedValue
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please tell me this wasn't it... I assumed it couldn't be this simple... that basic troubleshooting had happened.

Comment: Sorry I mean't it changes the value even when the statement returns true.

Comment: @user3191666 if that's the case, then please edit your question and add the code of `CheckListBox()` function, the problem might be in there.